# Setting up a public server

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

I am comfortable with web page development and PHP, but have always used an FTP and a live public domain for testing. I'm lucky enough to have a very fast internet connection and this has worked out fine. I just set up EasyPHP though as a local server. After being shown Opera Unite, I became interested in setting up a public server with my computer. I know that EasyPHP is not "ideal" for doing this, and I know that doing this for any seriously used website is infeasible. However I know that it is possible, and would greatly appreciate some help in doing it, either with EasyPHP or another set up I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create your own server, either as a VM, or on physical hardware, Ubuntu Server has a [LAMP-in-a-box option](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP):

[image: "Install LAMP Server"]
<sub>(source: [debianadmin.com](http://www.debianadmin.com/images/ubuntulamp/new/1.png))</sub>

This gets you a box pretty similar to what you'd expect to have in your hosting environment.

If you want to stay on Windows, consider [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

The sky is the limit here.  Just remember that ISP's might block certain traffic or ports due to your being on a consumer connection.  Have you set up a dynamic DNS service so you can follow your test box when your IP address changes?  I use dyndns.com and have had good luck with them.  Then go ahead and set up Apache or whatever you want to test and plug away.  I think you will find it an invaluable learning tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to your ISP for a static ipaddress for your home internet connection. Here in Australia that costs me $10 extra per month. Not sure about other countries.
If using a LAMP, you might want to virtualised your pc...run the server in virtualbox or vmware before opening it up to the world.

Also, ISPs usually restrict (choke) upload speeds from home internet connections (specifically so they aren't used for webhosting). Your outgoing internet speed can be tested using ookla speedtest. Internet modems often display link speeds too.

For example mine is less than 1/8th my download speed so for me, running anything from home is very very slow.

In addition to that, I find it's actually a lot faster to work from an online webserver than using WAMP on my desktop PC (my CPU is an I 7 720...perhaps a faster one would he better)

Why not get something like a $10/month  Vultr VPS? (1 CPU, 2GB RAM, 55GB STORAGE).. install a free control panel like Cyberpanel, Vesta, Centos Web Panel, or Virtualmin on it....you can't go wrong with that kind of setup.