# How can I safely set up a Public Server at Home

Tags: networking, security, ubuntu-14.04

Before posting I looked at a couple questions that looked promising but didn't really answer my question:

- [Setting up a Public Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/28213/setting-up-a-public-server) - This is more for local development, I am talking more of a production server, I can deploy code to, and have my customers interact with from their home.
- [Setting up a home DNS server](https://serverfault.com/questions/318159/how-to-set-up-a-public-dns-server-on-linux-server) - I don't need to set up my own DNS server, I don't think, because I have a hosting provider whose name servers I can use.

### Scenario

I run my own sole proprietorship and am getting to the point where I want to develop a few apps to automate some of the more menial things, like quoting projects, sending invoices, and things of that nature. Some of these apps would require MySQL database connections, as well as web forms to submit data, that will need to be secured.

The business I run is something I do on the side of my regular full-time job as a Full-Stack Software Engineer. The income from it is inconsistent enough that it doesn't justify a monthly server fee. Before anyone says it, I do understand how cheap cloud servers have become, but due to the nature of this inconsistent income, it would feel like throwing money away. However, depending on the answer to my question, I may have to just bite the bullet.

### Question

My question is **What are some "safe" ways to run a public server from your home?** For example, my hosting provider has name servers, so after *making the server public* can't I just point my host's name servers at my server's IP address to make it resolve without a host entry?

I am also looking for some insight into the security pros and cons of running your own server from home, verses using a cloud service. I've used a VPS cloud service (Digital Ocean) before, and understand how often bots hit them once they're turned on.

The **most ideal** situation in my mind, would be to have some way to give only my customers access to my home public server. Some kind of set up like a white list, so all they had to do was give me their IP, and I could add it to a config which would allow them to *see* my server -- ideally without a host entry. I like the idea of VPNs, but I don't want to require that level of tech-savvy from my customers.

Maybe I am way off base, but I could really use some insight into whether I can safely run a server from home. Some of the safety concerns I have are not:

- Broadcasting my home address to the internet
- Creating a serious hole to my home network
- Other things I haven't thought about

Maybe it's better for me to use a Cloud Server, I'm just not sure. Would my **ideal situation** mentioned above, even be an adequate solution?

Also, any helpful links/instructions/terms to Google would be much appreciated, but not required as I could just ask another question.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Have you read the numerous questions already on the site about setting up a home server (and why you shouldn't)?

Comment: Before I submitted my question I tried looking and didn't find anything, so I submitted it. Now that you say that though, it seems I should have Googled instead.

Comment: Your residential agreement with your ISP actually precludes you from running servers to the Internet, not that people don't do it anyway, but don't be surprised when CGN, or something else from the ISP, blocks you. The ISP may also ban you from Internet access for violating your terms of service.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm not sure where you live, but I can guarantee each ISP has different TOS. How can you make such a broad statement? My ISP Is NorthWesTel, you think they have the same residential agreement as Verizon?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, all the residential ISPs have such a term, including NorthWesTel. It is number 68 on page 7 of 12 of the _NORTHWESTEL TERMS OF SERVICE_, Effective October 1, 2016.

Comment: Good find, i did read that earlier but not that section. It does say "unless authorized", I may call and ask about my server too see what they say. Its different up north since they charge per GB so they make more money regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do this. Running servers at home is a hole in the ground that you throw money into.

The pro of running your services in cloud services is that you have highly skilled security engineers making sure things are safe at ever level they control, and other skilled personell to make sure your service stays up, your data stays intact, and your resources are quickly provisioned. This isn't even mentioning availability, which you can't hope to beat with running a service out of your residence without investing thousands on infrastructure that will continue to be many fold more expensive than using - for example - quickbooks online and Harvest for billing (less than $20 a month).

If you want to host production services yourself, you'll definitely want to have a good amount of experience in this field. It would be cheaper to pay someone a few dollars a month rather than spend a few months to years educating yourself.

Comment: Not to mention it probably violates the TOS of your ISP to run services from a standard residential broadband line (particularly services you make a profit from).

Comment: I save money by hosting at home, but as @RyanBolger said, there can be legal issues. I don't generate income from my server. But I do host my moms sites in return for her paying for my domain and SSL. I also save on hosting costs. In all, I pay nothing but electricity now. Upfront cost was about 2/3K but I also pass-through GPU and use it as my main workstation. (Typing on it now!)

Comment: I actually save money as well, but my home lab was originally built as (and still is) a gigantic OpenStack lab that's now built around K8S. I offer logins to friends and colleagues to simulate real world load and issues, etc. I could make it more public, but I'd need to invest an uncomfortable amount into my ISP.

Comment: Well I feel better knowing that you host a server at home, I would include that in your answer. It makes you look less like "I'm just a security nut" vs "I'm experienced in this and it's not worth it"

Comment: Another point is the security of sensitive data. There is no cloud, it's just someone else's computer, and regardless what does the contract says, you cannot ensure they don't monitor or downright steal your data stored in there.
If you run a server "at home" or least in your company, they would need to physically break in to steal the data, or break in using zero-days, which is harder to do without trace.

Answer (score 0):

As @SmallLoanOf1M said, don't run your own server from home, unless you feel qualified enough to run a server for someone else. Running a public server in the internet is not an easy task, and your server (at home or not) may end up serving malware, attacking other servers, or just vandalized outright.

You can find plenty of very cheap providers. Just search for VPS (Virtual Private Server) and you can find a couple for less than $10 a month. That is probably less than you will pay in power for running a server 24x7. And you don't need to buy the server, buy spare disks, spare power source...

Even if you run a VPS, you asked about ways to ensure only your clients can access it. Asking them for their IP address is going to be a nightmare. IP addresses are usually ephemeral, so they will probably have to give their IP to you **every single day** they want to access it. You got yourself a new full-time (I mean 24x7) job: inserting IP addresses on the firewall.

What you could do is to create a VPN and only allow users to connect from it. OpenVPN is easy to setup, but usually requires the client to install and configure their side, and that is not very straighforward for the average user. PPPTP or L2TP are easier on the clients, and is secure enough unless your clients are being targeted by skilled hackers or politicians.

There are a couple freelance sites that you can pay people to setup a server for you. The users there have a reputation to care for (like us here), and can charge less than a couple hundred to set up a server for you. If you want a secure server in the least time possible, this is the best alternative: rent a VPS and pay someone to setup it for you.

And you probably don't realize, but unless your router/modem is configured to block WAN requests, your IP is already public and some ports are acessible from anyone.

Comment: I rent with "all included" so power hasn't been a concern, but I do realize I probably spend a lot on power for my server. But, I use it for my own home gaming machine, so money wise, I may have bought this beast anyway! Also, how can I learn to run a server for someone else if I don't let myself be the guinny pig?

Comment: If you have a business, and it depends on the server, it's not wise to be your own ginny pig and set it up if you are not skilled enough.

Comment: Very True,  im unsure the ops level of skill or if its an already established business or in it's infancy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to say that I also tried to find similar questions and found yours to be the best worded question demonstrating the correct basic ideas/worries but still enough knowledge to get it done if you decide to.

**I was and am all for the idea of home server, but it should be done because you want to learn EVERYTHING about networking from top to bottom. If you just want it to work with minimal work, you'd save money and time by paying a service to host for you.**

To start, I'd like to say I have been running a home server for probably 5 years (man time flies). My main site is https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/wiki. I run everything on a VMWare ESXi tower which I also passthrough my GPU to use as my main workstation. (To much $ to get a powerful server and workstation for me)

I have had hacking attempts back when I used to host SSH on port 22. But eventually I just closed SSH to myself from public since its the most bot-attacked server surface in existence.

I'll start by addressing your highlighted portion of the question then get onto a few things I "learned" along the way (in regards to hosting a home server, I learned TONS about linux, but you can do that without hosting a home server).

***What are some "safe" ways to run a public server from your home?***

First off is your idea of a whitelist without VPN.

`The most ideal situation in my mind, would be to have some way to give only my customers access to my home public server. Some kind of set up like a white list, so all they had to do was give me their IP, and I could add it to a config which would allow them to see my server -- ideally without a host entry. I like the idea of VPNs, but I don't want to require that level of tech-savvy from my customers.`

Personally, I think that now-a-days VPNs are not as uncommon as you might think and are very easy to configure for the end client. My 60+Yr old mother had it for her corporate network. (Worst case you could TeamViewer in and setup for them). **VPN's allow the most concrete firewall experience from your perspective, just forward the VPN ports and thats it on the Gateway**

I did want to address the term "public". All IP's that are connected to the WAN (Internet) are "public". I assume you mean more like 'broadcast my home IP' as in anybody can ping freesoftwareservers.com and get my home IP. If you don't host public websites then only your clients should have your domain name and it won't show up in google etc so it shouldn't be considered "public".

If security is your main concern, I'd go that route and setup a domain name with "Dynamic DNS" updating for your home network. I doubt you can get a static IP from your ISP for a home ISP subscription. (I won't talk about the legalities of running a server at home, but lets say that I used to be with a major US ISP and never had a complaint). How I have DNS setup for my VPN is vpn.freesoftwareservers.com points to my home gateway. I then have a "Dynamic DNS" client that pings my domain name hoster every X Minutes and updates it if changed. I generally never have my home IP change unless I reboot the gateway. In this way you can setup your VPN certs to use that DNS name and know it should resolve.

- My Personal Thoughts I'd like to pass on

I started messing with servers while gaining my degree in computer networking and cyber security, so it seemed logical to do it "the hard way". **The beauty of a home server is you have to learn EVERY STEP. Nobody does it for you. Also, you will likely want to learn about Hypervisors/VM's and that's a years worth of learning right there!**

When I first started, I had 1 MB Upload, but this was mostly about me having access to my home network. Once I got 20MB Upload I was able to host moderate traffic on a simple txt based site without issues, but this can be hard to find. Also, **I moved a few times since I setup my server which was inevitable downtime.**

My Biggest Downfalls were

- Downtime when moving or rebooting
- NOT LEARNING CLOUD SERVICES

I want to be a sysadmin and I am way more knowledgeable on some matters, but lack familiarity with the GUI's of Major Cloud Vendors. But, once you understand what the GUI is doing, navigating a GUI is much easier vs click and test.

--Clearly I need to wrap this up, but this topic is dear to me!

In short, I think security wise you would be fine with a VPN if you are a SMB and could save money by doing things yourself. You also get cool hardware to play with, but you have to want to learn really bad. For me, it was instant love, you will either start and have 0 patience for learning/fixing problem after problem or find its fun and challenging. You can "Whitelist IP's" but your clients can't have DHCP IP's then, otherwise I'd use passwords + VPNs and re-issue every X Days.

There may be legality concerns with running a server on a home ISP. You could call and record a conversation where you ask point blank if it is ok. My site is non-profit so while its public, its not really money generating.

Can you handle a bit of downtime, because it will happen unless you do home + cloud.

If you really want to learn + have the best/cheapest setup I would have home server + cloud backup. The cloud servers can be charged based on bandwidth and usage. So if they are not being used because your home server is "up" then you won't get charged "much" for the cloud servers. This takes you into High Availability which is super fun to learn and crazy difficult! But I'm going to guess not needed, if you can plan your downtime as well, it helps clients.

That's it, If you do decide, I hope that you will take a look at my site, I think it has a lot of resources a home server enthusiasts could utilize, but know my site doesn't do much "teaching". Its more copy and paste-able code snippets that work for me.